# Usage and purpose of variable-length cells?

Tags: protocol

The [Tor protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/tor-spec.txt) version 1 uses 512-byte cells to obfuscate traffic patterns:

> Traffic flowing down the circuit is sent in fixed-size ``cells'',
>   which are unwrapped by a symmetric key at each node (like the layers
>   of an onion) and relayed downstream.

yet it seems as though protocol versions 2-4 allow variable-length cells (see the spec linked above, search for variable-length).

Are those ever used in practice? What is the purpose of variable-length cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the 2014 DRAFT v1, [Tor Design Document](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/papers/tor14design.pdf) (which seems to be more up-to-date than the [version](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html) in the Tor SVN repository).

Cells are discussed in section 4.1 (page 5).

The short answer is: varying the length of cells makes detecting Tor traffic more difficult. You can't just keep an eye out for cells of 512 bytes.

> Fixed-size cells provide some resistance to traffic analysis but are
>   inefficient, so some control cells are variable length, where the
>   ability of an attacker to detect their presence doesn’t affect
>   security. Fixed-size cells also make the
>   packet-size distribution of Tor distinctive, contrary to the goal
>   of protocol-fingerprinting resistance. Therefore a variable length
>   padding cell was introduced (but is currently unused)
>   to allow the implementation of schemes to disguise packet
>   length.

Note: I'm unsure if the variable-length padding cell, mentioned in the final sentence, has actually been implemented since this document was created.

Comment: Thank you. The observed packets lengths vary widely, with some cells occurring more often. This explains it. (Data being still sent in 512-byte cells, meta-cells in various sizes). PS: I had not seen any changes to the original design paper from 2004).