# Update on Tor design paper

Tags: protocol

@Richard Horrocks [gave a pointer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/8887/9411) to the updated [Tor design document of 2014](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/papers/tor14design.pdf).

Are there any new updates available publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is the latest paper on tor design. It will most likely be updated when tor 0.3.x is in a stable build. https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0303-alpha-released 
Watch there blog to see new versions released.

Comment: Probably reference the [tor-spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt).